# search dynamically from any table

Tags: dynamic, abap, opensql

I want to make a function module that make the same query, for example:

Select column_id from table_name where column_name = name_value.

I want to pass the table_name, column name and name_value, so, no matter what table is, I can get the id of the provided name. 
Could you lead me in how to do that in abap using function modules?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is there any reason not to use `RFC_READ_TABLE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you took the following parameters as input.

```
DATA: table_name  TYPE string VALUE 'MARA',
      column_id   TYPE string VALUE 'MATNR',
      column_name TYPE string VALUE 'MTART',
      name_value  TYPE string VALUE 'HALB'.
```

First, dynamically create a table of the type you will select into.

```
DATA: results TYPE REF TO data,
      tablety TYPE string.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <results> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.

tablety = table_name && '-' && column_id.
CREATE DATA results TYPE TABLE OF (tablety).
ASSIGN results->* TO <results>.
```

Then use a dynamic query to fill the table.

```
DATA: condition TYPE string.
condition = column_name && ` = name_value`.

SELECT (column_id) FROM (table_name)
  INTO TABLE results
  WHERE (condition).
```

Pass back the generically-typed reference to the calling program.

Comment: Hey, I tried to copy your solution but I always get the error "results is not a internal table"